# How to test code within then block following a promise with Jasmine?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I have the code below and I want test it as much as possible. I'm just scratching my head how to test that two line within the then block of the `authenticationService.authenticate()`. I have searched back and forth, but I haven't found any usable information.

When I checked whether the broadcast is fired, then the result was false because originally there is a broadcast message which triggers the whole code.

```js
function shellController($location, $rootScope, $scope, authenticationService, authService, common)
    {
        $scope.$on('event:auth-loginRequired', function ()
        {

            var user = {
                userName: 'visitor',
                password: 'visitor'
            };

            authenticationService.authenticate(user).then(function (result) {

                $rootScope.$broadcast('event:username-changed');

                authService.loginConfirmed();
            });

        });
    }
```

How can I simulate that when the `authenticationService.authenticate()` returned successfully - it is not object of the test whether it returned successfully or not - and whether the `$rootScope.$broadcast('event:username-changed');` is invoked - this is the test subject?

Comment: You simply want to confirm if the `event:username-change` event has been broadcasted and authService.loginConfirmed() is invoked?

Comment: Yes. That is correct!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main point in testing promises is to know that promises can be resolved or rejected by executing `$rootScope.$digest()`. Another point is to mock the promise returned by a specific function that returns a promise (either by returning a resolved promise or a rejected promise). By doing so, provides you facilities to control the flow of your tests. The test below shows you how to do this:

**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/MEj3FBUUlDPXkbnZLeKs?p=preview)**

**script.spec.js**

```
describe('shellController', function() {

  var locals,
      shellController,
      $q;

  beforeEach(module('app'));

  beforeEach(inject(function($controller, $location, $rootScope, _$q_) {

    $q = _$q_;

    locals = {
      $location: $location,
      $rootScope: $rootScope,
      $scope: $rootScope.$new(),
      authenticationService: {
        authenticate: jasmine.createSpy('authenticate')
      },
      authService: {
        loginConfirmed: jasmine.createSpy('loginConfirmed')
      },
      common: {}
    };

    shellController = $controller('shellController', locals);

  }));

  describe('event:auth-loginRequired', function() {

    it('should authenticate user', function() {

      locals.authenticationService.authenticate.and.returnValue($q.when());
      locals.$rootScope.$broadcast('event:auth-loginRequired');

      expect(locals.authenticationService.authenticate).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
        userName: 'visitor',
        password: 'visitor'
      });

    });

    describe('when user authentication succeeds', function() {

      var spy,
          result;

      beforeEach(function() {

        result = {};
        locals.authenticationService.authenticate.and.returnValue($q.when(result));

        spy = jasmine.createSpy('event:username-changed');
        locals.$scope.$on('event:username-changed', spy);

        locals.$rootScope.$broadcast('event:auth-loginRequired');
        locals.$rootScope.$digest();

      });

      it('should broadcast an event `event:username-changed` to all scopes', function() {
        expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
      });

      it('should call authService.loginConfirmed()', function() {
        expect(locals.authService.loginConfirmed).toHaveBeenCalled();
      });

    });

    describe('when user authentication fails', function() {

      var spy;

      beforeEach(function() {
        locals.authenticationService.authenticate.and.returnValue($q.reject());

        spy = jasmine.createSpy('event:username-changed');
        locals.$scope.$on('event:username-changed', spy);

        locals.$rootScope.$broadcast('event:auth-loginRequired');
        locals.$rootScope.$digest();

      });

      it('should not broadcast an event `event:username-changed` to all scopes', function() {
        expect(spy).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
      });

      it('should not call authService.loginConfirmed()', function() {
        expect(locals.authService.loginConfirmed).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
      });

    });

  });


});
```

Comment: Man, it is fantastic! Thank you very much! You helped me a lot, not just answering the question, but also the whole testing stuff. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to test the promise behavior or just the logic in the success callback?

If it is just the callback then I would move from an anonymous function to its own function and test that without the promise.

Otherwise I think you can use $httpBackend in your test to trigger the promise.

Comment: I want to test the logic in the success callback. However, I rephrased the question because it wasn't clear enough.